# Getting List has no rows for assignment to SObject error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I am new to SFDC. I have two Custom Objects both are having different VF Pages in my 1st custom object `Registration__c` I have one field `Email_id__c`. Every time if user enters value on Email field it should be Auto populate on my 2nd Custom Object `FeedbackFrom__c` Registered Email Field.

My Apex Coding is:

```
public class CurrentRecordIdDemoController{
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public String parameterValue {get;set;}
public Registration__c Reg{get;set;}

    public CurrentRecordIdDemoController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        Reg = [select id ,Email_id__c from Registration__c where id =: currentRecordId ];
        parameterValue = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
    }
}
```

My Vf Coding is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Registration__c" extensions="CurrentRecordIdDemoController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Your Email" collapsible="false">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Reg.Email_id__c}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Testing parameter" collapsible="false">
            Name is <b>{!parameterValue}</b>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

please any help me out from this issue.

Comment: are you passing the id in url like.. /apex/pageName?id=001212121  something  ??? .. ``ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id')`` this line of code will get the id from url

Comment: @Ronald I tried your code and it works fine. The only problem could be the URL parameters which you're passing.

Comment: i have two different pages for each Custom object i need to pass value From Cus_Obj 1 to Cus_Obj 2 how can i achieve this..???

Comment: @Ronald Then you should have method like this: `PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/vf_page_name?id=recordId&nameParam=value); pageRef.setRedirect(true); return pageRef;`. This will return control to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Controller extension then you don't need to use separate query to get the record.

Just use  [StandardController.getRecord()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm) method like this.

```
public Registration__c Reg{get;set;}
private Registration__c RegList;

public CurrentRecordIdDemoController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.Reg = (Registration__c)controller.getRecord();
    parameterValue = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because query will return in List.Although only one row data retrieved , it still in List.

To be safe use

```
List<Registration__c> regList =[select id ,Email_id__c from Registration__c where id =: currentRecordId ];

Reg =regList[0];
```

Please refer to this link :  [Error, "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000159853&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

Check for following two things:-

1. The visualforce page url has paramter named `id'
2. If Id is present then make sure you have records in the database related to the `Id`

Here is the way to prevent from exception issue. Always use `List<SomeObject__x>`. Ex:

```
public Registration__c Reg{get;set;}
private Registration__c RegList;

public CurrentRecordIdDemoController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        RegList = [select id ,Email_id__c from Registration__c where id =: currentRecordId ];
        if(RegList.size()>0)
        {
           Reg =  RegList[0];  
        }
        parameterValue = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
    }
```

If you are opening the page from detail page/related list button click. You can directly get the If by

```
currentRecordId  = controller.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the code is not getting any current id from `ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');` this line of code.
you can use the constructor to use the **StandardController.getRecord()**

Try the below code:

```
public class CurrentRecordIdDemoController{
public String currentRecordId{get;set;}
public String parameterValue{get;set;}
public Registration__c Reg{get;set;}
public CurrentRecordIdDemoController(){
  currentRecordId =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
  Reg =[select id,Email_id__c from Registration__c where id =: currentRecordId ];
}
public CurrentRecordIdDemoController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
   parameterValue =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
  }
}
```

To get the name from the current record:

```
Registration__c var =(Registration__c)controller.getRecord();
parameterValue =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
```

Regards,
Akshay